# Regex match everything between to strings - Complex

Tags: regex

I have this code:
http://pastebin.com/7MZHVu2T

I need to get everything between 'public function addTopicParticipants' and 'public function deleteTopics'

I tried:

```
/public function addtopicParticipants(.*?)public function deleteTopics/
```

This is the only thing I remember.

Comment: In what language? What have you tried?

Comment: Hello. In regex. I tried a lot of expressions that I searched in Google, but none of them could get it. I can't understand why.

Comment: Show some of the things you tried. And regex isn't a language, it's something you do within a language (like PHP, Perl, C#, Javascript, etc).

Comment: Oh, I'm using PHP, but i want the regex to find that. Added what I tried and can remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/public function addTopicParticipants(.*?)public function deleteTopics/s', $text, $match;

$found = $match[1];
```

The `s` modifier allows `.` to match newlines.

Tested [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gs&regex=public%20function%20addTopicParticipants%28.%2a?%29public%20function%20deleteTopics&input=%20public%20function%20addTopicParticipants%28%20%24topicID,%20%24invitedUsers,%20%24readingMemberID%20%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20INIT%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24topicData%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20=%20%24this-%3EfetchTopicData%28%20%24topicID%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24memberData%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20=%20IPSMember%3a%3aload%28%20intval%28%20%24readingMemberID%20%29,%20%27extendedProfile,groups%27%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24currentParticipants%20=%20%24this-%3EfetchTopicParticipants%28%20%24topicID%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Can%20access%20this%20topic?%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%20%24this-%3EcanAccessTopic%28%20%24memberData%5B%27member_id%27%5D,%20%24topicData,%20%24currentParticipants%20%29%20!==%20TRUE%20%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Exception%28%20%27NO_PERMISSION%27%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Build%20invited%20users%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24invitedUsersData%20=%20%24this-%3EcheckAndReturnInvitedUsers%28%20%24invitedUsers,%20%24memberData,%20count%28%24currentParticipants%29%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%20isset%28%24invitedUsersData%5B%20%24topicData%5B%27mt_starter_id%27%5D%20%5D%29%20%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%20%24memberData%5B%27member_id%27%5D%20==%20%24topicData%5B%27mt_starter_id%27%5D%20%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Exception%28%20%27CANT_INVITE_SELF%27%20%29;%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20function%20deleteTopics%28%20%24memberID,%20%24ids,%20%24rawSQL=NULL,%20%24hardDelete=false%20%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//-----------------------------------------%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Grab%20data)

Comment: It doesn't work: http://regexr.com?34kle

Comment: I think that regex tester is buggy. I tried it at regexpal, see the link.